# PasteScript and PasteDeploy not working with Python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, cygwin, paster

We are using PasteScript and PasteDeploy to launch our python service. Things were great until we moved to Python2.7 from Python2.6.

PasteScript = 1.7.5, PasteDeploy = 1.5.0

```
# Launch
$ paster serve --reload conf/dev.ini
  Starting subprocess with file monitor
```

After putting some debug statements in paster, we found that the entry point is in serve.py

```
# In serve.py        
def command(self) 
    ...
    app = self.loadapp(app_spec, name=app_name,
                           relative_to=base, global_conf=vars)
    ...
# In deploy.py
def loadapp(uri, name=None, **kw):
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)

def loadobj(object_type, uri, name=None, relative_to=None, global_conf=None):
    print "I see this"
    context = loadcontext(object_type,uri, name=name, 
                  relative_to=relative_to, global_conf=global_conf)
    print "I do not see this"
    return context.create()
```

The process simply terminates at the loadcontext call with no error. I have done the same exercise with Python2.6 and it works as expected. So I am assuming my PasteScript and PasteDeploy are not compatible with Python2.7 but cannot confirm since the website does not state compatibility.

Can someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Couple of issues:

1) Paster was failing because the "requests" module was not installed. Its interesting to note that Paster did not throw any error and died silently.

2) So I tried installing "requests" and that failed too with no specific error. Just said InstallationError: egg_pkg_info failed

We guessed may be it was the 64-bit Cygwin that was screwing things up. So went ahead and performe the same exercise on 32-bit Cygwin. Everything worked as expected. So at the end of the day, it was neither Paster nor Python.